# Including flot.time plugin in node application

Tags: node.js, flot, node-modules

Using `flotjs` node-modules to draw graphs, but could not as it was giving error as : `Time mode requires the flot.time plugin`. When checked  in `node_modules/flotjs` directory found that `flot.time.js` is already present. As I need `time` mode in the options so this plugin is necessary. How to remove this error or get the `flot.time.js` imported ? Gave a try with absolute path also in the same file where import need to be done, but it did not work. How to import `flot.time.js` into existing project ?

Comment: Are you sure that flot.time is not loaded? Maybe it's loading after you call it? Make sure you're loading it first. If that's not the case - provide some examples how you do it.

Comment: Plotting flotjs graph using react component and when I don't use mode time then the graph is getting plotted fine. @Mort are you saying that while giving absolute path it is not taking ?

Comment: I'm saying that I didn't know how you're embedding this library - thus I proposed to check if its loaded before execution. If you for ex. try to use $ before <script> with jQuery it just won't work.

Comment: Not using `<script>` tag anywhere instead using `import` and `require` . The way I have imported node module is `var plotMultiLine = require('flotjs');` and then using `new plotMultiLine(element, data,options) ` to draw the graph.